# Can workflow send e-mail to SP Groups?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to send an email with attachment using Useful Sharepoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities from Codeplex.

I've put my recipients in an SP group but when I try to email to that group I get an error
that's it's not in the format of an e-mail address.

Does that mean that SPD can't e-mail to an SP GROUP? Or is it a bug in the Custom Activities?

Answer (score 2):

The Email workflow activity that ships with SharePoint 2007 is quite limited. If you need more control then have a look at [this article](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/send-rich-emails-with-attachments-from.html) that uses the Workflow Power Pack to send emails with attachments. (I worked on this product so consider me biased).

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this a couple times. Workflows (at least in WSS 3) don't resolve SP groups to email addresses, so you can't just email a SP group and have it go to everyone in the group. The only solution we found was to create a custom feature or webpart to handle that portion of the work, or hard code the email addresses in the workflow itself (which isn't really a good practice for future manageability).